# How to interpret making "angles of $\mathbf {30}^\circ$ and $\mathbf{60}^\circ $ with the horizontal line parallel to the ground"?

Tags: trigonometry

> A rope dancer was walking on a loose rope tied to the top of two equal posts of height $9$m. **When he was $\mathbf 3$m above the ground, it was found that the stretched pieces of the rope made angles of $\mathbf {30}^\circ$ and $\mathbf{60}^\circ $ with the horizontal line parallel to the ground** . Find the length of the rope.

I could not understand the given highlighted condition and could not figure out  the diagram. can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I understand it. I drew a picture.

[image]

Comment: what do I need to find then?

Comment: The question was "I could not understand the given highlighted condition and could not figure out the diagram. can anyone help with this?". Now it is up to you to try.

Comment: but to solve it where is the right angled triangle?

Comment: I'm gonna need you to think about it for a little longer.

Comment: ok then let me try for sometime

Comment: ok I got it with the help of ratios

Comment: Sure. The arrow that says "3m", if you extend that upwards to the blue line, then it makes a right angle and you will have two $30-60-90$ triangles.